# Multiple OS X clients - Time Machine backup to NAS?

Tags: backup, mac-osx, network-attached-storage, time-machine

We have about 15 OS X desktop machines - mainly iMacs, some MacBooks and Mac Pros. Each user has a local account on the machine, and a portable USB disk for a Time Machine backup.

I want to coordinate the backups to a central NAS, and I'm thinking about something like the Synology DS2411+ (I know there are only 12 bays; we may need 2 of them!), allocating one disk each for each client machine.

Our network hardware is gigabit capable, and all clients connect at 1000baseT.  I'm concerned about the network utilisation. I know the initial full backup will take a long time, but I'm prepared to do that one machine at a time overnight. But what about when multiple clients do their incremental TM backups at the same time? What kind of impact could that have on the network?

Is this a feasible network based solution?  Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is feasible, but it might take some hackery to get it working. As far as I know, the only officially supported (read: easy-to-implement and stable) network TM backup is when backing up to either a Time Capsule or an OSX Server.

It is possible, though, to back up to an afp or smb share - just don't depend on it being reliable. I had it working for a while at home and it needed constant prodding to get backups working.

Comment: OSX Server really is the best option for doing a number of clients via TimeMachine. The third party options are few and far between.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually using a network TM backup strategy for our office.  We have a smaller office than yours (7 MBPs/iMacs) backing up to a central server over gigabit ethernet.  Network IO doesn't seem to be an issue throughout the day.

I know my incremental backup tends to be a few hundred megs a couple times a day.  Over gigabit, this is really a non-issue, just a few minutes of network traffic.  Once a week my backup is around 10GB, which takes a little longer.  I've noticed that under the big backups, if I'm utilizing a lot of system resources, my system slows down significantly while doing the backup.  I expect this is due to the slow hard drive we're using as a backup device and my system is trying to write data over the network, and it's just not being written on the other end fast enough.

My backup server is a Ubuntu box, and I allocate 200GB for each user to backup.  The drive situation isn't as robust as I'd like (1 single 7200 RPM drive in a RAID1) but it's alright for now.  There's some tutorials on how to get this to work, it's a big of a pain to set-up but it seems like it's working alright for everyone.  The solution uses Netatalk and AFP, and there're some tutorials out there on how to get it to work [this one is pretty comprehensive](http://www.kremalicious.com/2008/06/ubuntu-as-mac-file-server-and-time-machine-volume/) and it has a lot of user comments.  It is the one I used to get our system set up.